# How to define 'Most' in Isabelle/FOL?

Tags: isabelle, quantifiers

I am trying to augment `FOL.thy` with the quantifier `MOST`, which I intend to define as the simple majority, i.e.,

```
(MOST x. P(x)) ==> card P(x) > card ~P(x).
```

I am not sure how to modify the `FOL.thy` file.
Under `axiomatization`, I thought to add:

```
Most :: "('a => o) => o"  (binder "MOST " 10)
```

and, beneath the `where` clause:

```
specM: "(ALL x. P(x)) ==> (MOST x. P(x))" and
mostI: "(MOST x. P(x)) ==> ..."
```

where "..." is the proper way of expressing the constraint as outlined above, w.r.t. the cardinality of `P(x)` and `~P(x)`. (Again, I wasn't sure on a good name here and suggestions are welcome.)

I thought to add an entry in the "symbols" section and, for lack of better ideas, chose to use delta:

```
Most (binder "∆" 10)
```

And likewise in the `notation` section.

1) How do I properly express the cardinality constraint?

2) What other things do I need to modify?

To the latter question, it might be helpful to point out that, ultimately, I want to assess whether a number of different conclusions are necessary, possible, or impossible, given premises that will include quantified assertions using 'Most' and 'All' (as well as conjunctions, disjunctions, etc.).

Comment: I edited your post s.t. `Most` is the basic constant (a usage would be like `Most (%x. P x)`) and `MOST` the corresponding binder (which is just nicer notation for the same constant, i.e., `MOST x. P x`).

Comment: Two questions: 1) which `FOL.thy` are you talking about? The one from the Isabelle2013 distribution? Then it should rather be `IFOL.thy` I guess (on which `FOL.thy` is based and which contains the basic constant definitions). 2) What do you mean by "symbols" section above?

Comment: Btw: For your definition to make sense you need a theory where you have cardinal numbers with a "less than" comparison. It seems that `FOL` alone is to weak for your purpose. (In `HOL`, e.g., the `card` function for the number of elements in a set is only defined on finite sets and thus would also not help in your case; unless you wanted a predicate `P` that is only true for finitely many "inputs" and whose negation is true infinitely often to be *Most*ly true.)

Comment: @chris, you are entirely correct that FOL is weak and I would need some HOL. I thought card was available within FOL.
As to your other comments - the 'symbols' section was simply a part of the file in which it seemed symbols were being defined. I have avoided doing the legwork of learning how Isabelle functions, because it's not really the goal of my project, but it seems I should put the time in. If you do decide to answer, I will mark it as being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a particular reason, it is generally better to take Isabelle/HOL as starting point for whatever application you have in mind.

The argument whether FOL or HOL is stronger depends on additional axiomatization.  Isabelle/ZF provides full Zermelo-Fraenkel set-theory on top of FOL, so it is more expressive than plain HOL, but its tools and libraries are almost 20 years behind.

Instead of starting at the bottom `HOL.thy`, you should enter the game at the top with theory `Main`, potentially with some further theories from `$ISABELLE_HOME/src/HOL/Library`.

Your sketches with `Most` remind me of [`$ISABELLE_HOME/src/HOL/Library/Infite_Set`](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL-Library/Infinite_Set.html) although that is about more interesting infinite sets.  There are further theories about ordinals and cardinals in HOL to be discovered.  It depends what is ultimately your application.